# Postgresql and pgAdmin III, what is character varying[]

Tags: postgresql, types, pgadmin

When creating a table in pgAdmin, there are two data types list for most entries, such as the following examples,

character varying,
character varying[]
or
bigint,
bigint[].

What is the significance of the data type followed by []?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This means postgresql array type that allows to store multiple values in a single table column. I.e. bigint[] means just array of bigint.

Answer (score 3):

As per this link
[Postgres Array Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html)

PostgreSQL allows columns of a table to be defined as variable-length multidimensional arrays.